# login to sql server using windows credentials from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have a asp.net webb aplication that use a sql server database, it connect to the sql server like this Data Source=ServerAdress;Initial Catalog=DbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx

And then there is users in the database, pretty straight forward... I now have a request to be able to login to the sql server using windows credentials instead of sql server user account like it is now. But isn't this kind of login restricted to Windows CE devices only?

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows CE has nothing to do with that. You need to use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server, but this is a bit more complicated with web apps. Start from this article [Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities). Then you can remove the user name and password from your connection string and connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication and the identity that you configured to be used.

Comment: What about  on this site  Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;  

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

Note that this will only work on a CE device.

Comment: This site doesn't provide trustworthy information. This statement is at least incorrect. Check the official Microsoft Docs for this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax

Comment: Ok, but if I use this connectionstring "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;  
    database=AdventureWorks;server=(local)" do you then not pass windows login to the connectionstring? I wonder beacuse there is a login page on the site and if I want to autenticate and connect to the database using windows credentials, and that page seem obsolete then, or?

Comment: First, in case you are using Windows Authentication (i.e. Integrated Security is true or SSPI), then Persist Security Info is meaningless. Simplified a bit, with Windows Authentication, the connection to the database will be made using the identity of the process, who established the connection. If your users logs into your web app with Windows Authentication too, then it is possible to pass this identity to the database too. If you use another (e.g. forms) authentication in your app, then your application pool's identity is important. Check the article I've sent you for more information.

Comment: Hmm, I have checked the link but as far as I understand it talk about the process that use the application pool which is the IUSR, in my case the same IUSR user will of course access the web site, but its not the IUSR user that login to the site